# Transposing column on data frame from multiple different tables

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, transpose, multiple-tables

I'm working with R Studio Version 1.0.143.

I need to transpose one column to become the name of the variables without losing information about the value (freq_var and freq_mut in this example).
Also, I need to know for which table the data came from (sample 1, 2 etc)

The main problem is how I add everything together even if one value in Gene is not present in Sample 1 but IS present in Sample 2 (NA's in the example)

I could do it manually, but my table contains thousands of values for each variable!

Sample 1

```
   Freq_var  Freq_mut   Gene
       2         2        A
       3         3        B
       2         5        C
```

Sample 2

```
   Freq_var  Freq_mut   Gene
       1         2        A
       1         1        B
       1         1        D
```

To:

```
           A(Freq_var)  B(Freq_var) C(Freq_var) D(Freq_var) A(Freq_mut).....
Sample 1        2            3           2           NA          2
Sample 2        1            1           NA          1           2
```